# Bootstrap collapse with Angular router

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap collapse as the example http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse .

Since I use Angular router, in `localhost/#/flow` page, how should I set `href` of collapse?

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="collapseOne">
```

If I set it to be `href="collapseOne"` or `href="/#/flow/collapseOne"` or `href="/#/flow/#collapseOne"`, the Angular router will route it to `localhost/#/`.

If I set it to be `href="/#/flow"`, it says `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/flow`.

So how should I set the `href` to enable collapse while stay in current page?

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse - angular-ui-bootstrap ex:http://plnkr.co/edit/9H9fr2iBqJjy76xrcKzA?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `data-target="yourID"`.  Twitter allows data-attributes, it worked for me.

As an aside, if you're using Angular, why not use a port of Bootstrap that is re-written by the AngularUI team found here [AngularUI's Bootsrap Components](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)